# Compile Qt program on Ubuntu 18.04 which will run on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-18.04

Interesting delema.

Trying to compile Qt program where Qt is build from source on 18.04 64-bit and run it on 14.04. The interesting part is trying to identify which libraries I need *this* time. The C++ ABI has changed.

Looking to see if anyone else has done this recently? Which libraries do I have to bring along? Yes, I know about ldd and readelf and have spent days trying this in various VMs. The problem is once you start bringing the C++ stuff over (because the ABI has changed yet again) you get to a point where your VM won't reboot.

Please don't suggest snappy, flatpak or one of those other new "container" solutions. Already wasted 3+ days on snappy. It's architecture specific and only supports building on 14.04 when it comes to Qt, at least the deployqt tool to make an AppImage does.

Did this years ago with this very program. Built a debian which would install on both 64-bit and 32-bit for every version from 12.04 to 15.04 including the short lived .10 and odd year versions.

I tried compiling QT with C++11 standard, but, it will no longer compile with that standard.

The incompatible ABI is the real killer.

It is more than one program so the hack of a shell script using LD_LIBRARY_PATH would bring considerable difficulty.

Appreciate insights.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you build statically? This is typically best solution to make backwards compatible executables.

Comment: No. Uses QWebEngine. Static not possible due to plugins, et-al.

Comment: Well, I guess then you have to either build everything on old platform, or force upgrade to new one.

Answer (score 0):

Please always develop applications on the oldest distribution you still want your application to run on. For example, if you want your application to run on all currently still-supported versions of Ubuntu, then develop your application on Ubuntu 14.04 and do not install any newer compilers or libraries than what it comes with.

This is how "backward compatibility" works.

Comment: While what you say about "backward compatibility" is true, since 2015 this has been building and deploying multiple times per day building on 15.10 and running on everything from 12.04 forward bringing very little along.

Comment: I came back and actually answered this question and someone on here deleted the answer. That was a long and hard won answer.